# Simpson's Rule, find an $N$ for $\;\int_1^5 \ln x \, dx,\;\; $ error $\leq 10^{-6}$

Tags: calculus

$$\int_1^5 \ln x \, dx\;\qquad\text{ error } \leq 10^{-6}$$

I know that my $K_4 = 24$ since the fourth derivative is $24x^{-5}$

$$\frac{24 \cdot 4^5}{180 N^4} \leq 10^{-6}$$

$$\frac{24 \cdot 4^5}{10^{-6}} \leq 180 N^4$$

$$\frac{24 \cdot 4^5}{10^{-6} \cdot 180} \leq  N^4$$

$$\left(\frac{24 \cdot 4^5}{10^{-6} \cdot 180}\right)^{1/4} \leq  N$$

This give me the wrong answer, I should be getting 23. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Note that $f^{(4)}(x)=-6x^{-4}$; you did an extra derivative. So you should instead use $K_4=6$.

Comment: I tried that previously and that was incorrect, I think my fourth degree derivative is correct because I have the integral of lnx, so I need to take the derivative of that to get the function, then the derivative 4 times to get the fourth degree derivative.

Comment: Are you sure the answer is supposed to be $N=23$? Normally for Simpson's Rule, $N$ is even.

Comment: $ 23 \leq N$ is the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You went "one too far" with the "fourth derivative" of $f(x)$: $$f^{(4)}(x) = -6x^{-4}\,.$$  The function you are starting with when taking derivatives needs to be: $\,f(x) = \ln x;\,$ which is the **integrand**, *prior* to integrating. (You are using Simpson's rule to **approximate** the integral, after all.) You took the fifth derivative of $f(x) = \ln x$, giving you $\left(f^{(5)}(x) = 24x^{-5}\right).\;$

So try applying Simpson's using $\;K_4 = 6$.

Note also that $N$ should be raised to the fifth power.
$$\frac{6 \cdot 4^5}{180 N^5} \leq 10^{-6}$$

Comment: I think that is correct actually, because I have the integral lnx, so to get the function I need to take the derivative, then to get the derivative I take the derivative of the function, and then three more times for the third degree.

Comment: This is correct, but it isn't enough.  Also the $N$ in the denominator should be raised to the $5^{\text{th}}$ power because the length of the interval is raised to the $5^{\text{th}}$ in the error term.  Making those corrections I still get $32$

Comment: I don't follow why N to the fifth is done.

Comment: @Ross and Paul: I'm getting $32$ as well. I think maybe $23$ was transposed (typo) in the solutions, where the intent was to print $32$?

Comment: Paul: we need for the exponent of N to match the exponent of the length of the interval $\,\left(N^5 \leftrightarrow 4^5\right).\,$

Comment: I don't follow why, my formula in the book doesn't do that.

Comment: Are you looking at a *different* example? (The exponent will vary, depending on the length of the interval.) Please trust that I'm trying to be helpful. Why would I steer you otherwise?

Comment: The general formula for Simpson's rule Error is $\frac{K_4(b-a)^5}{180N^4}$

Comment: If that's what you've learned, then certainly, stick with it. You should get $76.44 \leq N$, approximately, using $N^4$. In any case, I suspect the solution has a typo.

Comment: I am but it doesn't match teh books answer.

Comment: This is another unfortunate case, I suspect, of a typo/misprint. simply change $K_4$ to be $6$, show your work, and you're good to go. Typos happen more often than they should, causing too many students needless confusion.

Comment: @PaulthePirate:  The reason $N$ is to the $5$th power is because the length of the interval is $\frac {b-a}N$.  As you take more points, the length of the interval is divided by $N$.

Comment: @amWhy: I know secretly you want to become a numerical analyst! :-) +1